# What is the simple way to detect emacs buffer has the regexp matched string, then execute a function?

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, org-mode

I want run a function `org-toggle-inline-images` each time when I open a new buffer which contains a link like this: `file:folder/file.jpg`.

How to do this ?

Comment: Why not leave the toggle always active?  `(setq org-startup-with-inline-images t)`

Comment: Thanks, I have not found this option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (when (re-search-forward "file:folder/file\\.jpg" nil :noerror)
        (org-toggle-inline-images)))))
```

It's not clear to me whether you want a regexp match or not. Are you looking for a specific filename, or a pattern?

If the former, use `search-forward` instead of `re-search-forward`, and then you don't need the regexp syntax.

If the latter, you'll need to sort out the regexp, in accordance with the org-mode 'link' syntax.

For the double-square-bracket link syntax, you could try this:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  ;; Enable inline images if there are jpeg images in the file.
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (catch 'done
        (while (re-search-forward org-bracket-link-regexp nil :noerror)
          (when (string-match "^file:.+\\.jpg" (match-string-no-properties 1))
            (org-toggle-inline-images)
            (throw 'done t)))))))
```

But I agree with lawlist's comment -- `org-startup-with-inline-images` seems to have you covered.

Comment: Right, the `org-startup-with-inline-images` is what I need. Thanks for your answer, it let me learn a lot.